# Drupal Views converts Twig variable to zero when performing operations

Tags: views, theming

I have a Drupal 8 view that has a counter in it. I want to have one behavior when the counter is odd and a different behavior in the counter is even. However, the counter is always evaluated as even.
Here's some code:

```
Counter: {{ counter }}
Counter is even: {{ counter is even }}
Counter is odd: {{ counter is odd }}
{% set foo = (counter + 0) %}
Foo: {{ foo }}
Foo is even: {{ foo is even }}
Foo is odd: {{ foo is odd }}
```

And the output:

```
Counter: 1
Counter is even: 1
Counter is odd:

Foo: 0
Foo is even: 1
Foo is odd:

Counter: 2
Counter is even: 1
Counter is odd:

Foo: 0
Foo is even: 1
Foo is odd:

Counter: 3
Counter is even: 1
Counter is odd:

Foo: 0
Foo is even: 1
Foo is odd:

Counter: 4
Counter is even: 1
Counter is odd:

Foo: 0
Foo is even: 1
Foo is odd:
```

As you can see, the counter is counting up. But, as foo demonstrates, whenever math is done on counter, it's always zero, so it always evaluates as even.

I've done counter.value as well, which doesn't change the fact that counter always registers as zero whenever there is an operation done on it. The output of dump(counter) is zero.

So, the question is: Why does counter always evaluate as zero and therefore even, although it's clearly counting up?

EDIT: 
It seems like the counter was coming through as something that would just always turn to zero when put into twig operations. We were able to fix the problem by adding a render function to the views core module, to return an integer value and not the array or whatever was being returned before.

Answer (score 0):

"The output of dump(counter) is zero" ... I think you don't have the twig debug environment enabled, otherwise you should see an array, for example with a `#markup` key inside:

```
{% set counter_value = counter['#markup'] %}
```